# How to add a new header to the arm-gnueabi toolchain?

Tags: c++, linux, arm, toolchain

I need to compile my c++ programm for an arm system with sqlite3 support.
For standard programms I've always used the `arm-linux-gnueabi` toolchain. But the `sqlite3.h` header file is not available in this toolchain.

How can I add the header file for sqlite3?

I installed it already for my native compiler: `sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev`.

The header file is available under `/usr/include/sqlite3.h`

Comment: The "toolchain" contains only headers that are specific to the tools themselves. In particular, that's Standard headers such as `<stdio.h>`. SqlLite is NOT part of the toolchain, and its headers therefore aren't either.

Comment: Yes, I know that. This is the reason for this question!

Comment: Let me rephrase the comment then. `sqlite3.h` is not, and should not be part of the toolchain. Therefore, the question "how to add it to the toolchain" is improper. The proper question is probably "how do I use headers from libraries?" Cross-compiling is a red herring.

Comment: It really depends on the distribution you're using. On Debian I use `xapt` to install cross libraries and headers, then `autotools` do the rest.

Comment: i use debain, too. so my xapt command would be like this: `sudo xapt -a armel -m libsqlite3-dev` and thats it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `-I /usr/include/sqlite3.h` to your CFLAGS or CXXFLAGS (or some other macro that is used to build those - "INCLUDE_FLAGS" or "INCLUDES" is often used for this purpose) in your makefile.

And of course, you will probably need to build the sqlite3 binaries for ARM using your cross compiler. Or you may be able to convince `apt-get` to install a precompiled ARM version of the code - sorry, not sure how to do that.

Comment: luckily i can install the headers on the arm system with `apt-get`
i will try to add those headers with `-I ...`

Comment: @baam depending on your platform, you may be able to `apt-get` from the target itself. I got lazy once and did that with ubuntu on a beagleboard.

Comment: Hi Mats,
if I try to add the header file like you suggested i get the following error: `cc1: warning: /usr/include/sqlite3.h: not a directory [enabled by default]`

but sqlite3.h exits at this location...

Comment: You should use `-I /usr/include` - which will tell the compiler to look there (after looking in the "default" locations, unless given some flag to remove default locations).